# Linear programming positive constraint conversion

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, canonical-transformation

So lets suppose we have the following linear problem:

$\min -x+2y$

$s.t$

$x-y\le6$

$x-3y\le12$

$x\ge0 ,y\le2$

and I want to use simplex to find the optimal solution. First we convert this problem to a max problem that's in canonical form. Constraints are already $\le$. We make $\min$ to $\max$ and then we need $\forall x_i,x_i\ge0$. But here i get a bit confused. $y\le2 $ is troubling me. I know that $y\le2 $ means $y$ could be negative. So i create this virtual variable $w=2-y$ and replace $w $ with $y$ in the problem , and then i have this linear problem to solve:

$\max x-2w$

$s.t$

$x-w\le8$

$x-3w\le18$

$x\ge0 ,w\ge0$

However using simplex for the above problem gives me a solution of $x=8,w=0$. but of course this is not a feasible solution for the original problem.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Some of your constraints are wrong, i.e. $ x - y \leq 6$ should translate to $x + w \leq 8$ after substituting $y = 2 - w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the substitution $y = 2 - w$ in the problem, which gives

$$
\begin{align}
& \text{max} & x - 2(2 - w) = x + w - 4 \\
& \text{s.t.} & x - (2 - w) \leq 6 \\
&& x - 3(2 - w) \leq 12 \\
&& x, w \geq 0.
\end{align}
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\begin{align}
& \text{max} & x + 2w\\
& \text{s.t.} & x + w \leq 8 \\
&& x + 3w \leq 18 \\
&& x, w \geq 0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You can also simplify the second constraint to $w \leq 5$.

Comment: is it not $\max x+2w$ since you multiply $-2(2-w)$ ??

Comment: You're absolutely right, edited it.